# Считать ли "главное" вводным словом?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

«Главное донести не слово, а образ».

Тут нужно ставить запятую после *главное*? Оно вводное?

Comment: @shampar А разве не нужно вынести точку за кавычки?

Comment: Фраза цитируется полностью и не в составе другого предложения. Точка неотделима от законченной фразы и потому она внутри кавычек.

Answer (score 2):

> *Главное (?) донести не слово, а образ.* Тут нужно ставить запятую после "главное"? Оно вводное?

Возможны варианты. Зависит от контекста и интонации.

См. возможные примеры:

1. *Что мне нужно сделать? **Главное, донести не слово, а образ.** Во-вторых...*
2. *Но главное сегодня не это. **Главное — донести не слово, а образ.***
3. *Это не главное. **Главное: донести не слово, а образ.***

В первом примере ***главное*** — вводное. Во втором и третьем примерах — подлежащее.

Comment: а может быть в этом предложении  обособлять "главное" вообще никак не нужно?

Answer (score 1):

1) Что является главным? **Главное** — (это) **донести не слово, а образ.**

Здесь *главное*  – подлежащее. Оно не может быть вводным словом, так как без него не будет предложения, а останется только словосочетание *донести не слово, а образ.*

2) Это не главное. **Главное — донести не слово, а образ** (вот что главное).

Здесь *главное* — сказуемое.

Таким образом, (при одинаковом оформлении) функция слова **зависит от контекста.**

Comment: а может быть в этом предложении обособлять "главное" вообще никак не нужно?

Comment: А как вы определите грамматику этого слова в  предложении? (Именно с этого надо начинать решение пунктуационной задачи). В любом случае (подлежащее, сказуемое, вводное слово) надо ставить запятую или тире.  Не обособляется слово "главное" только в функции определения: Главная задача - донести не слово, а образ.