# Какая часть речи "главное"?

Tags: пунктуация

После слова "главное" нужна запятая или тире? Или ничего не надо?

**Главное донести не слово, а образ.**

Comment: Существительное среднего рода. См. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/274122/главное

Comment: Вам уже отвечали на этот вопрос. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434216/%d0%a1%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%93%d0%9b%d0%90%d0%92%d0%9d%d0%9e%d0%95-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc

Comment: В том-то и дело, что однозначного ответа никто не дал. В итоге оказалось три варианта: тире не нужно, нужно, и нужна запятая.

Comment: Ответ зависит от контекста.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Считать ли ГЛАВНОЕ вводным словом?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434216/%d0%a1%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%93%d0%9b%d0%90%d0%92%d0%9d%d0%9e%d0%95-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc)

Answer (score 1):

> Вопрос о том, является ли вводное слово частью речи, остаётся
> открытым. Часть таких слов традиционно относят к наречиям (вероятно,
> конечно, видимо), часть — к союзам (итак, во-первых), сопровождая их
> пометой «в значении вводного слова».

[**ГЛАВНОЕ,** *вводное слово*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_136)

Указывает на то, что говорящий намерен высказать важную, особенно существенную мысль.

> *«Вот мы и дома, – промолвил Николай Петрович, снимая картуз и встряхивая волосами. – Главное, надо теперь поужинать и отдохнуть».*
> И. Тургенев, Отцы и дети. *Но, главное, Женька столько сил отдавала
> тишине, что на остальное почти ничего не оставалось.* Б. Васильев, А
> зори здесь тихие. *Надежным, крепким, главное, послушным артельщиком
> казался Архип...* В. Астафьев, Царь-рыба.

*Главное, донести не слово, а образ.*

Comment: Если это вводное слово, то где подлежащее? А часть речи - существительное (или субстантивированное прилагательное)

Comment: Люси, давайте свой подкованный ответ в студию! Я тоже учиться хочу! Не, ну что я за урод! Ведь всё ж так очевидно... Существительное, потом тире...